# How i can render Hyperstack Component on erb view?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, isomorphic, hyperstack

For example i have a erb page with many logic. I wanna create user messages on this page with Hyperstack. How i can render Hyperstack component on this erb Page?
Upd:
I know this is possible because the Hyperstack Component is embedded in aplication.erb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

erb file:

```
<%= react_component('TestComponent') %>
```

hyperstack component:

```
class TestComponent < HyperComponent
  render(DIV) do
    'Its works'
  end
end
```